# Join two tables with a lesser than or equals condition in join

Tags: mysql, sql

Below two tables I have with sample data. Table A contains dollar rate (into Indian rupee) as per year, and Table B contains amount per year. I want to convert
dollar into rupee as per year.

```
Table A
Rate Year
47   2001
49   2003
55   2004

Table B
Amt Year
25$ 2001
34$ 2002
```

Question: for first record (year 2001) we have entry in both tables so we can do this easily by using below query

```
sel A.Rate * B.Amt
from A,
     B
where B.year = A.year
```

But for second record (i.e. year 2002) we do not have entry in table A (which is rate table), so for these kind cases I want to use rate value from previous year (i.e.: 47 rupee from year 2001.)

Comment: Tag properly the next time!!! Now Christian Palmer spent lots of time and energy writing an Oracle answer.

Comment: @New_User I hope you got the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution :

```
select A.rate*B.amt 
from A,B
where B.Year = (select max(year) from B where B.year <= A.year);
```

Answer (score 0):

Oracle :  use the LEAD analytic function so you can work out the validity period of each rate.

[documentation for LEAD](https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/lag-lead-analytic-functions#lead)

This is my code :

```
SELECT
 trx.*
,rates.rate_start_date
,rates.rate_end_date
,rates.rate
,trx.amount * rates.rate     rup_amount
FROM
 xxcjp_forex_trx     trx
 --this inline view works out the validity period of each rate by ordering all
 --the rates and working out the start date of the next row.  It uses analytic 
 --function LEAD
,(SELECT
   xfr.rate_date         rate_start_date
  ,xfr.rate
  ,xfr.currency
  ,(LEAD(xfr.rate_date) OVER (ORDER BY xfr.currency, xfr.rate_date))-1    rate_end_date
  FROM
   xxcjp_forex_rates      xfr
 )     rates
WHERE 1=1
AND trx.trx_date BETWEEN rates.rate_start_date AND rates.rate_end_date
AND rates.currency = 'RUP'
ORDER BY
 trx.trx_date
;
```

Based on this data :

```
CREATE TABLE XXCJP_FOREX_RATES
(rate_date        DATE
,currency         VARCHAR2(20)
,rate             NUMBER
)
;


CREATE TABLE XXCJP_FOREX_TRX
(trx_date         DATE
,currency         VARCHAR2(20)
,amount           NUMBER
)
;

INSERT INTO XXCJP_FOREX_RATES VALUES (TO_DATE('01/03/2016','DD/MM/YYYY'),'RUP',47)  ;
INSERT INTO XXCJP_FOREX_RATES VALUES (TO_DATE('03/03/2016','DD/MM/YYYY'),'RUP',49)  ;
INSERT INTO XXCJP_FOREX_RATES VALUES (TO_DATE('10/03/2016','DD/MM/YYYY'),'RUP',55)  ;

INSERT INTO XXCJP_FOREX_TRX VALUES (TO_DATE('01/03/2016','DD/MM/YYYY'),'USD',10) ;
INSERT INTO XXCJP_FOREX_TRX VALUES (TO_DATE('02/03/2016','DD/MM/YYYY'),'USD',20) ;
INSERT INTO XXCJP_FOREX_TRX VALUES (TO_DATE('03/03/2016','DD/MM/YYYY'),'USD',30) ;
INSERT INTO XXCJP_FOREX_TRX VALUES (TO_DATE('04/03/2016','DD/MM/YYYY'),'USD',40) ;
INSERT INTO XXCJP_FOREX_TRX VALUES (TO_DATE('05/03/2016','DD/MM/YYYY'),'USD',50) ;
INSERT INTO XXCJP_FOREX_TRX VALUES (TO_DATE('06/03/2016','DD/MM/YYYY'),'USD',60) ;
INSERT INTO XXCJP_FOREX_TRX VALUES (TO_DATE('07/03/2016','DD/MM/YYYY'),'USD',70) ;
INSERT INTO XXCJP_FOREX_TRX VALUES (TO_DATE('08/03/2016','DD/MM/YYYY'),'USD',80) ;
INSERT INTO XXCJP_FOREX_TRX VALUES (TO_DATE('09/03/2016','DD/MM/YYYY'),'USD',90) ;
INSERT INTO XXCJP_FOREX_TRX VALUES (TO_DATE('10/03/2016','DD/MM/YYYY'),'USD',100) ;
```

Comment: Great answer, just too bad OP is using MySQL - which afaik doesn't support LEAD. (Quite annoying when wrong products are tagged.)